# Is there an example of a manifold with fundamental group $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

I feel a little confused because I was told that there exist some manifolds with fundamental group $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$, but I can’t find an example, On the other hand, since any manifold $M$ has an orientable $2$-cover, which means $\pi_1(M)$ has a subgroup of index $2$ which seems to be a contradiction with $\pi_1(M)$ can be $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: What your covering argument shows is that the orientation cover of a manifold with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ must not be connected, as indeed happens for every orientable manifold.

Comment: I would like to point out that any finitely presented group is the fundamental group of [some manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15411/finite-generated-group-realized-as-fundamental-group-of-manifolds) (in a similar way that any group is the fundamental group of a 2-complex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are infinitely many $3$-manifolds whose fundamental groups isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z$.

Indeed, for $\mathrm gcd(3,q)=1$, take any [Lens space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space) $L(3,q)$.

Comment: all $L(3,q)$ are diffeomorphic. there is only one closed 3-manifold with fundamental group $\Bbb Z/3$ up to diffeomorphism, and two up to oriented diffeomorphism.